# Как проверить, спит ли диск?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi, bat

Если в Windows включено автоматическое отключение дисков при неактивности, то как программно проверить, спит диск или включен, естественно, не разбудив его при этом?

Comment: [GetDevicePowerState](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winbase/nf-winbase-getdevicepowerstate) - судя по Remarks - оно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а как хэндл получить?

Comment: Там же написано как - можно использовать хендл любого файла на этом устройстве, или хендл самого устройства. Хендл получается вызовом `CreateFile`, там в примечаниях подробно описывается как открыть устройство. Только не помню, нужны ли права администратора для открытия устройства как readonly. Можно попробовать запросить доступ только к атрибутам.

Comment: @freim, а разве при открытии файла устройство не проснётся? Оно ж прозрачно для приложений работает. Или там надо какой-то особый флаг передать? Или фишка именно в открытии устройства?

Comment: При открытии файла проснется, разумеется. Но ведь активный хендл может все равно присутствовать, если файл до засыпания открылся. У вас вопрос не вполне конкретный, так что и ответ универсальный. Но если хендла нет, то надо диск открывать. От запроса на чтение атрибутов проснуться не должен, но это надо экспериментировать, конечно.

Comment: Если нужно сразу при запуске определить, то вероятно надо искать какие-то глобально открытые хэндлы, ассоциированные с диском. Ну и сам запуск, получается, должен быть с какого-то иного устройства.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот таким способом удалось проверить PowerState диска и не разбудить его при этом. Моя домашняя система очень тихая, запуск и остановка диска отчетливо слышны. Более весомое доказательство: при повторных запусках состояние не изменяется, в отличие от варианта с получением хендла от файла.

Правда не без ложки дегтя, требуются права администратора и нужно знать порядковый номер проверяемого физического диска в системе.

99% кода примеры с PInvoke, моя только компоновка в рабочий вариант.

```
void Main()
{
    String status = String.Empty;
    bool fOn = false;
    var driveX = 1;
    var hFile = CreateFileW($@"\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE{driveX}", FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, FileAttributes.Offline, IntPtr.Zero);
    bool result = GetDevicePowerState(hFile, out fOn);
    if (result)
    {
        if (fOn)
        {
            status = "Disk is powered up and spinning";
        }
        else
        {
            status = "Disk is sleeping";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        status = "Cannot get Disk Status";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(status);

}

//https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CreateFile
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr CreateFileW(
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string filename,
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAccess access,
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare share,
     IntPtr securityAttributes,
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode creationDisposition,
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAttributes flagsAndAttributes,
     IntPtr templateFile);

//https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetDevicePowerState
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool GetDevicePowerState(IntPtr hDevice, out bool pfOn);
```

Ограничения:

- системный диск спит только когда спит вся система (во всяком случае на Windows).
- проверка не имеет смысла, если физический диск в системе единственный, он в любом случае будет активен, если вся система не спит (см. выше).
- не уверен насчет SSD и прочих сменных носителей, проверять было не на чем, на единственном SDD живет система и он никогда не спит.

Answer (score -2):

Можно подумать в сторону командной строки, что то вроде 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И что конкретно "можно подумать"? Поясните ваш скриншот, пожалуйста. Где на нем указано что диск спит или не спит?

Answer (score -4):

Никак. За остановку диска при отсутствии обращений к нему отвечает прошивка диска. Винда может остановить диск только когда за компом никто не работает.

Comment: У меня 2 диска и второй гудит  только когда кликнешь по ярлыку диска)